# PHP file not running in Netbeans (possible configuration issue)

Tags: php, netbeans, configuration, webserver, sftp

I'm trying to run a PHP file in Netbeans. The project is a simple PHP project that was created from source files taken from a hosted webserver that I use. An SFTP connection is used. When I run the project, I am met with the following error;

**Not Found**

**The requested URL /Connect.php was not found on this server.**

**Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
      <head>
      <title>Test Code</title>
      </head>
<?php
      $servername = “example.example.com”;
      $username = “admin_user”;
      $password = “1111222233334444”;
      $dbname = “test_exampleDB”;

// Create connection
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
  echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Project configuration;

1. Run as: **Remote Website (FTP, SFTP)**
2. Project URL: **http://example.net**
3. Index File: **Connect.php**
4. Arguments: **None**
5. Remote Connection: **SFTP (setup during the creation of project)**
6. Upload Directory: **sftp://example.example.com/home/user/public_html/Datbase**
7. Upload  Files: **On Save**

Should I be using a different configuration? Should the servername be an IP or the actual site name instead?

Any help would be much appreciated.